# Sharing Google Spreadsheet with C# and REST

Tags: c#, rest

Ii'm trying to share a Google Spreadsheet using C#. Because the Google Data 3.0 API hasn't been ported to C# yet, I've been trying to interact with their RESTful web service. I haven't worked with REST before.

Google asks for the following:

```
POST /feeds/default/private/full/<resource_id>/acl HTTP/1.1
Host: docs.google.com
GData-Version: 3.0
Authorization: <your authorization header here>

 <entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gAcl='http://schemas.google.com/acl/2007'>
  <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind'
term='http://schemas.google.com/acl/2007#accessRule'/>
  <gAcl:role value='writer'/>
  <gAcl:scope type='user' value='new_writer@example.com'/>
</entry>
```

I'm using the code below to try to access the web service, but it's not working for me. What about this code is incorrect, given the requirements above?

```
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;
        entry  = bunchaxml;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "text/xml";
        request.Headers["GData-Version"] = "3.0";
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(entry.ToString());
        }
        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            string sc = response.StatusCode.ToString();
            string scd = response.StatusDescription.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //LogError
        }
```

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: If you're using .NET 3.5 or 4.0 you should be able to use the WCF REST starter kit. They have an HttpClient that makes it really simple to access ant REST service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The credentials you are using are not appropriate for the Google APIs.  You can see how it is done here http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps.html

Basically, you POST to a login endpoint with a your username and password and they return you a auth token that you can then use in future requests.

Comment: I think you're right about the authentication, but the link you gave me was for Installed Apps. I think web apps are supposed to use OAuth.